# Replicate Column-1 values in rest of the columns for non blank values only

Tags: r

I have data frame like this -

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name-1 | 3.5 | NA | 3 |
| Name-2 | Na | NA | 1 |
| Name-3 | NA | 7 | NA |
| Name-4 | NA | NA | NA |
| Name-5 | 1 | NA | 1 |

I am looking for the result like given below

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name-1 | Name-1 |  | Name-1 |
| Name-2 |  |  | Name-2 |
| Name-3 |  | Name-3 |  |
| Name-4 |  |  |  |
| Name-5 | Name-5 |  | Name-5 |

Can any one help me with the codes. I about 200 columns in this I need to repeat this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Duck, but for any number of columns, assuming first column is always named A:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(-A,  ~if_else(!is.na(.), A, "")))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. May ask further help?.  How can I get the below table from the above result

| CT | OG.Name |
| ---- | -------------- |
| B   | Name-1     |
| B   | Name-5     |
| C   | Name-3     | 
| D   | Name-1     |
| D   | Name-2     |
| D   | Name-5     |

Answer (score 3):

Try this using `across()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% mutate(across(B:D,~ifelse(!is.na(.),A,'')))
```

Output:

```
       A      B      C      D
1 Name-1 Name-1        Name-1
2 Name-2               Name-2
3 Name-3        Name-3       
4 Name-4                     
5 Name-5 Name-5        Name-5
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(A = c("Name-1", "Name-2", "Name-3", "Name-4", 
"Name-5"), B = c(3.5, NA, NA, NA, 1), C = c(NA, NA, 7L, NA, NA
), D = c(3L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop approach:

```
for(col in 2:ncol(your_data)) {
  your_data[[col]] = ifelse(!is.na(your_data[[col]]), your_data[[1]], "")
}
```

Or the same thing using `lapply` instead:

```
your_data[-1] = lapply(your_data[-1], function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), your_data[[1]], ""))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. May ask further help?. How can I get the below table from the above result | CT | OG.Name | | ---- | -------------- | | B | Name-1 | | B | Name-5 | | C | Name-3 | | D | Name-1 | | D | Name-2 | | D | Name-5 |

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(B:D, ~ case_when(!is.na(.) ~ A)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("Name-1", "Name-2", "Name-3", "Name-4", 
"Name-5"), B = c(3.5, NA, NA, NA, 1), C = c(NA, NA, 7L, NA, NA
), D = c(3L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
> cbind(df[1], ifelse(!is.na(df[-1]), df$A[row(df)], ""))
       A      B      C      D
1 Name-1 Name-1        Name-1
2 Name-2               Name-2
3 Name-3        Name-3
4 Name-4
5 Name-5 Name-5        Name-5
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c("Name-1", "Name-2", "Name-3", "Name-4", 
"Name-5"), B = c(3.5, NA, NA, NA, 1), C = c(NA, NA, 7, NA, NA
), D = c(3, 1, NA, NA, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. May ask further help?.  How can I get the below table from the above result

| CT | OG.Name |
| ---- | -------------- |
| B   | Name-1     |
| B   | Name-5     |
| C   | Name-3     | 
| D   | Name-1     |
| D   | Name-2     |
| D   | Name-5     |